# Spring Boot - How to configure Environment Variables?

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables

I want to be able to specify Environment Variables in my Spring Boot Application. I have an external library that I'm using that requires environment variables, and the values to those variables will change according to the environment where we are deploying.

For example, in application.properties of my packaged spring boot jar "myapp-boot-packaged.jar", I add the following property:

foo=bar

The equivalent for java -Dfoo=bar -jar myapp-boot-packaged.jar

Comment: what was the problem exactly? are you asking how to set env variables and values through spring boot application?

Comment: Yes. I have an external library that expects the environment variables to be set. However, the external library does not recognize it when I define the variables in application.properties. I am able to run the application by specifying the environment variables through the IDE's Run configuration. I am looking for a way to package it into my application.

Comment: Turns out that the issue was within the jar that was provided.

Comment: Please, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

You have to declare in `application.properties`

```
foo=${bar}
```

The when you run it:

```
Java -jar myApp.jar -Dbar=someValue
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply run it informing in the command line like this:

```
$ java -jar myapp-boot-packaged.jar --foo='bar'
```

[Spring Boot Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args)

Answer (score 1):

### Use properties from environment or property source

You don't have to configure anything it's supported natively.

> Spring Boot lets you externalize your configuration so that you can
>   work with the same application code in different environments. You can
>   use properties files, YAML files, environment variables, and
>   command-line arguments to externalize configuration. Property values
>   can be injected directly into your beans by using the @Value
>   annotation, accessed through Spring’s Environment abstraction, or be
>   bound to structured objects through @ConfigurationProperties.

It's done for you, so what you still have to do is to declare your variable in :

- Command Line arguments (--foo=bar)
- JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
- Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
- OS environment variables.

---

### Properties by environment (Profiles)

If you want to use property per environment (local, dev, production) you can use profiles, a dummy example is to have `application-[profile].properties` (where [profile] could be dev, prod ...) along with `application.properties` in the your classpath or externalized (refer to using [spring.config.location](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) ).

**Note that application profile specific properties override those in application.properties**

Comment: Thanks. The external library reading the environment variable is not able to read it from my application.properties file. I am looking for a way to package it within my application using profile specific properties file.

Comment: Turns out that the issue was within the jar that was provided.